# jquery delegate not working with list item

Tags: jquery

I'm using an older version of jquery (1.6.2) and can't seem to get delegate working.  I have a list that I'm trying to use delegate on a click event but it fails after the list is reloaded.

Here is my current code:

```
$(".image_result").delegate("li", "click", function() {

//$('.image_result li').click(function() {
    var imgInfo = $(this).attr('id').split(':');

    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?')) {
        $.post('delete_image.php?image_id=' + imgInfo[0] + '&user_id=' + imgInfo[1], function(data) {

            if (data.st) {
                var resp = data.html.split("|");

                $('#imageStats').html(resp[0]);
                $('#imageTable').html(resp[1]);
            }
            else {
                alert("Yikes, something went wrong");
            }
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

The imageTable div now holds the new list items (image_result)

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post the HTML structure as well

Comment: when you reload the list, are you clearing out and re-setting up the lis, or are you destroying and recreating the .image_result element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to `.delegate()` is that you cannot destroy/replace the item in the jQuery object (in this case `.image_result`.  Doing so, kills your jQuery event handler.  The selector you use in the jQuery object must be static (not getting destroyed or replaced).

In your case and assuming that `.image_result` is a child of `#imageTable`, you can probably use this instead:

```
$("#imageTable").delegate(".image_result li", "click", function() {...});
```

because `#imageTable` is not getting replaced so it's event handler survives changes to the child objects and the selector passed as an argument to `.delegate()` zeroes in on the right `li` objects.

Comment: That was the issue.  setting delegate on the parent div worked.  I didn't realize that.  Thanks so much...I learn something every day :)